# Get system time accurate to 0.1ms (100 microseconds)

Tags: java, android, time

I am trying to conduct some extremely accurate data measurements. For this, I need to be able to get the current time in microseconds, accurate to 100 microseconds (Or more). I can't seem to be able to find any way on the [Android Developer](http://developer.android.com) website. Device specific answers are acceptable (I have access to a Nexus 7, so any answers involving that would be awesome).

I had originally thought it possible to use the system sensors which give times accurate to the microsecond, however I have no idea how to set and/or tell if the sensors are accurate. Not to mention whether these event. - [SensorManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html)

Is there any way to get the time in microseconds on an android device that is accurate to within 100microseconds?

Comment: Can you just use a timer or does it have to be the actual time?

Comment: note the you're running on a OS which limits your ability to sample data at high frequency

Comment: ^^This. Android is not remotely a real-time operating system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [System.nanoTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29). according to doc

> Returns the current timestamp of the most precise timer available on
>   the local system. This timestamp can only be used to measure an
>   elapsed period by comparing it against another timestamp. It cannot be
>   used as a very exact system time expression.
>
> **Returns**
>
> the current timestamp in nanoseconds.

From the java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29) you will get some extra explanation of it

Comment: Do you know if there is anyway to find the accuracy of said timer?

Comment: I think it should complete your need as according to doc it is the most precise timer. But I am not sure whether there is any way to find the acuracy of this. If i find any I will update the answer. You also inform us if you find any :)

Comment: Sure thing, I only needed to find this out, because if it's accuracy is 1ms then I need to find a device with a better clock.

Comment: I think it should be better than that.. please check the updated link of my answer.. and offcourse you can check by coding